# How can i use Excel JavaScript API in my lwc component

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, api, excel

I want to use Excel JavaScript API in my lwc component. but not sure how to import this Api. throwing error Excel not defined when I use it
[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you please add the snippets of the code that you think might be throwing the error, we don't have much to go on from your question.. :)

Comment: Welcome to SFSE, please read [Why should I not upload images of code when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/), then provide the code used to fetch contacts (where you set the list passed to the datatable). Once copy-pasted the code you could format it clicking `{}` or you could read how to enable [syntax highlighting for code](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting)